# AWS CLI redshift authorize-endpoint-access gives 'Invalid choice' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli

I am trying to authorize-endpoint-access command for aws cli redshift.

My command is

```
aws redshift authorize-endpoint-access --profile djis --cluster-identifier redshift-cluster-tf --account 123123123123
```

And it gives me and error:

> Invalid choice: 'authorize-endpoint-access', maybe you meant:
>
> * authorize-snapshot-access

But here is the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/redshift/authorize-endpoint-access.html) of the command (command exists)

My cli version is aws-cli/2.0.54

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was stupidly simple. The command was added in version 2.1.34 as informed in this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6510).

So, needed a cli upgrade.